# Yahtzee, using a dictionary instead of list of attributes

Tags: python

So my issue is that currently I have code for my yahtzee (I will not post all of the code, but the important stuff is looking like this (and it works):

```
from terminaltables import AsciiTable

class Player:
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name=name
        self.ones=0
        self.twos=0
        self.threes=0
        self.fours=0
        self.fives=0
        self.sixs=0
        self.abovesum=0
        self.bonus=0
        self.onepair=0
        self.twopair=0
        self.threepair=0
        self.fourpair=0
        self.smalladder=0
        self.bigladder=0
        self.house=0
        self.chance=0
        self.yatzy=0
        self.totalsum=0

def welcome():
    global spelarlista
    spelarlista=[]
    print("Welcome to the yahtzee game!")
    players = int(input("How many players: "))
    rounds=0
    while not players==rounds:
        player=input("What is your name?: ")
        rounds=rounds+1
        spelarlista.append(Player(player))
    table_data = [["Name"] + spelarlista,
        ['Ones'] + [player.ones for player in spelarlista],
        ['Twos'] + [player.twos for player in spelarlista],
        ['Threes'] + [player.threes for player in spelarlista],
        ['Fours'] + [player.fours for player in spelarlista],
        ['Fives'] + [player.fives for player in spelarlista],
        ['Sixs'] + [player.sixs for player in spelarlista]]
    table = AsciiTable(table_data)
    table.inner_row_border = True
    print(table.table)
    spelarlista[0].add()
welcome()
```

The issue right now is that I want to add a dictionary instead of all those self.ones, self.twos etc. If you take a look at my welcome method, you can see that I have `[player.ones for player in spelarlista]`and I need this to assign the players points, how can I fix so this work for a dictionary instead? The dictionary is neccesary for my next method, add, if you were curious!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dict_names = ['ones', 'twos', ..., 'totalsum']
self.dict = {name:0 for name in dict_names}
```

and to access you'd use `player.dict['fours']` instead if `player.fours`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help! Greatly appreciated!